# Why is other powershell script run twice?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that checks whether disk has a certain amount of free space. If not, a pop-up appears asking for a yes or no. If yes, then an alarm is set to 1 and then another script that deletes files from folder runs. My issue is that it seems to delete twice the number specified in the script.
Main script:

```
$limit_low = 0.1 # låg gräns 10%
$DiskD = Get-PSDrive D | Select-Object Used,Free | Write-Output
$DiskD_use = [math]::Round(($DiskD.Free / ($DiskD.Used + $DiskD.Free)),2)
 
if( $DiskD_use -le $limit_low ) {
    Write-Host "RDS-server har för lite utrymme på disk D $diskD_use < $limit_low" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow    
    
    $ButtonType = 4
    $Timeout = 60
    $Confirmation = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
    $ConfirmationAnswer = $Confirmation.popup("Clear disk space?",$Timeout,"No space",$ButtonType)

    If( $ConfirmationAnswer -eq 6 ) { 
        Write-Host "Kör script Diskspace.ps1 under P:\backupscripts"
        & c:\dynamics\app\JDSend.exe "/UDP /LOG:c:\dynamics\app\Fixskick.log /TAG:Lunsc2:K_PROCESS_LARM_DISKUTRYMME "1""
        & P:\BackupScripts\Delete_archives_test.ps1 # here i call the other script       
    } else { 
         Write-Host "Gör ingenting"
         & c:\dynamics\app\JDSend.exe "/UDP /LOG:c:\dynamics\app\Fixskick.log /TAG:Lunsc2:K_PROCESS_LARM_DISKUTRYMME "0""
    } 
}
```

Other script:

```
# List all txt-files in directory, sort them och select the first 10, then delete
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp -File Archive*.txt | Sort-Object | Select-Object -First 10 | Remove-Item -Force
```

Cheers

EDIT

So it would be enough to enclose the first statement like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp -File Archive*.txt) | Sort-Object | Select-Object -First 10 | Remove-Item -Force
```

?? Funny thing is i tried to reproduce this today at home with no effect. Works as intended from here, even without parens.
Further I am painfully ignorant about how to use `foreach` statement, as it doesn't pipe the bastard :)

```
foreach ($file in $filepath) {$file} | Sort-Object | Select-Object -First 10 | Remove-Item -Force
```

Tried to put the sort and select-part in the `{}` too, but nothing good came of it. As i'm stuck in the pipe and don't understand the `foreach` logic.

Comment: Download procmon from Sysinternals (Microsoft), start it as admin and execute your script. Stop procmon from gathering info (can get very much in very little time!) and filter on files/your script/folder or whatever to verify that your script is only called once and that only 10 files are removed (or not).

Comment: so your 2nd script is deleting 20 files instead of 10? i don't know why it does that ... but there are times when using `G-CI` to feed a pipeline can cause it to re-read the list. i would enclose the `G-CI` call at the start of your pipeline in parens to force it to read the items _all at once_.

Comment: If it reads the the files twice and sends both instances down the pipe. Sort still has to wait to receive all of them.  I'd then expect it to delete half the number of files eg 5 instead of 10, the other 5 would error no?  Since half the 10 would be duplicates.  Interested to hear your take on that.

Comment: So the problem here is just with `Delete_archives_test.ps1` ? What happens if you run the second script by itself? Before running it, try changing it to use `Remove-Item -Force -Verbose` instead. This will tell you exactly which files were deleted. Or you can use `-WhatIf` if you don't want to actually delete anything.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey _"but there are times when using G-CI to feed a pipeline can cause it to re-read the list"_ -- Can you elaborate on when and why that happens?

Comment: @zett42 - think about what a pipeline does ... it takes ONE thing, does stuff to it, and then passes that one thing to the next stage. in the case of `Get-ChildItem` that means it can re-read the same file when something changes the file. by wrapping the call in parens you force `G-CI` to grab all the files at once ... and THEN pass them to the pipeline. it is possible you are seeing your "does it twice" because you are changing the file list in the midst of using the file list.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Interesting, do you have a link for further reading? I couldn't find anything documented about this behaviour.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I think you should post that as answer. When removing files or renaming them or altering the files in any other way and sending them straight away in the pipeline from Get-ChildItem you always need to let it complete first and then pipe the result through the pipe. I've seen many questions where that was the case and since an accepted answer is easier to find then answers in comments..

Comment: @zett42 - i have not been able to find anything specific on that. i do recall reading several threads on the powershell subreddit where the problem was solved by forcing the file list to be read ONE time only.

Comment: @Theo - done! let me know if it needs re-working. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

your problem appears to be caused by how your pipeline works. [*grin*]

think about what it does ...

- read ONE fileinfo item
- send it to the pipeline
- change/add a file
- continue the pipeline

that 3rd step will cause the file list to change ... and may result in a file being read again OR some other change in the list of files to work on.

there are two solutions that come to mind ...

- wrap the `Get-ChildItem` call in parens
  that will force one read of the list before sending anything to the pipeline ... and that will ignore any changes caused by later pipeline stages.
- use a `foreach` loop
  that will read the whole list and then iterate thru the list one item at a time.

the 2nd solution also has the benefit of being easier to debug since the value of your `current item` only changes when explicitly modified. the `current pipeline item` changes at every pipeline stage ... and that is easy to forget. [*grin*]